# Solve differential equations $dx + (xy-1 + \frac{1}{y})dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Help me solve this differential equations:

$$dx + (xy-1 + \frac{1}{y})dy = 0$$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: you can solve this by making this equation of type $\frac{dx}{dy}+xy=1-\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: WA says this here $$\text{Solve}\left[x=c_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2} y(x)^2}+e^{-\frac{1}{2} y(x)^2}
   \left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\frac{1}{2}
   \text{Ei}\left(\frac{y(x)^2}{2}\right)\right),y(x)\right]$$

Comment: this will be of form $\frac{dx}{dy} +f(y)x=f(y)$ type

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the equation seems very simple but answer surprised me.

Comment: Me too, something simple becomes complicated

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  Some DE look very simple but they are monster.

Comment: @TheStudent  so after we write this in form whats then? may be chadge of variable?

Comment: @12345654321 yes but method will be same

Answer (score 2):

Let us re-write it as $Mdx+Ndy=0$
$$ydx+(xy^2-y+1)dy=0 ~~~(1)$$
Here $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=1, \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=y^2$
So the integrating factor is $I=e^{\mu}$, $ \mu=\int \frac{y^2-1}{y} dy$
So $$I=\exp[y^2/2-\ln y] =\frac{e^{y^2/2}}{y}.$$ Multiplying (1) by $I$, the exact ODE is $$ e^{y^2/2}~dx+ (xy^2-y+1) \frac{e^{y^2/2}}{y}~ dy=0$$
Finally its solution is given as
$$\int e^{y^2/2} dx ~~\text {[treat y as const]}+\int(1-y) \frac{e^{y^2/2}}{y} dy~ \text{[terms not containing x]}=C$$
$$\implies x  e^{y^2/2} -\sqrt{\pi/2}~Erfi (y/\sqrt{2})+\frac{1}{2} Ei (y^2/2)=C $$

Comment: You are right, I have edited my Answer.

Comment: Ahmed no problem. I don't think there is a solution with elementary functions whatever we try.

Comment: +1 for all your efforts. For text you can use the latex \$ \text {your text here}\$

Comment: Thanks for this tip.